# How to get a BrowseForFolder dialog callable from within a ArcGIS Pro DockPane (WPF)

Tags: c#, arcgis

I want to specify a folder (gdb) in ArcGIS Pro in a DockPaneView but cannot find out on how to get a 'Select Folder' and/or 'Select File' dialog can be called from within a DockPane.

The closest I got was to use 'BrowseForFolder' from ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Dialogs but here I am getting the problem that I have to provide the 'parentWindow' as an IntPtr.

All I need is a button in a DockPaneView that onClick is calling a 'Select Folder' dialog.

Comment: If you need a parent window handle in a WPF application, use System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper

Comment: Thanks Klaus for the fast and correct reply.
Funktioniert wunderbar. ;-)

Comment: So I changed my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a parent window handle in a WPF application, use System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper